# React navigation Navigator hierarchy

Tags: react-native

I have a switch navigator when ı pass the login page to on my home ı got a drawer and bottom tab navigator if ı don't click bottom tabs my drawer doesn't work and send an error

```
const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeScreen: Home,
    SettingsScreen: setting
})
const Draw = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Draw: AppTabNavigator
})
const Auth = createStackNavigator({
    Login: login,
    Home: Home,
    Settings: setting,
})
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: Auth,
    App: Draw,
})
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this tutorial for the correct react-navigation hierarchy.

https://medium.com/async-la/react-navigation-stacks-tabs-and-drawers-oh-my-92edd606e4db